# How to make 2 of everything in an array list?

Tags: java, arraylist, double

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Integer> two = new ArrayList<Integer>;
    two.add("Kyle");
    two.add("Randy");
    two.add("Shaun");
```

The goal of this program is to make two of all of the strings so it will print out like this 
but I am not sure of how I would do this.

kyle

kyle

randy

randy

shaun

shaun

any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: There's a mismatch with your data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> strings2 = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String s : strings) {
  strings2.add(s);
  strings2.add(s);
}

for(String s : strings2){
    System.out.print(s);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Um...you could provide something like a static utility method that iterates over the collection, printing each entry twice,

```
private static void print(List<String> list){
    for(String s : list){
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```